# Setting state from axios response and using it in render

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-state-management

I have this current situation in react where the state is not getting set and if set cannot be used in render.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`url`)
        .then(function(response){
            const test = response.data;
            this.setState({
                data:test
            });
        }.bind(this));
      setTimeout(function test(){
          console.log('filterdata',this.state.data);
      },2000);
}
```

This is my sample code that I have been trying to use but the problem here is even though I am setting the state the global this does not contain the value. I have done bind to prevent the same. I have tried two other things as well

```
componentDidMount() {



    axios.get(`url`)
        .then((response)=>{
            this.setState({
                data:response.data
            });


});
      setTimeout(function test(){
          console.log('filterdata',this.state.data.templateFields);

      },6000);
}
```

as well as this

```
componentDidMount() {

    var self = this;

    axios.get(`url`)
        .then(function demo(response){
            self.setState({
                data:response.data
            });


});
      setTimeout(function test(){
          console.log('filterdata',self.state.data.templateFields);
      },6000);
}
```

The last one has the value in self but cannot be used in render where I am using "this" like this

```
<ul className="filter-options">
                            {
                                this.state.data.map(function(val){
                                <p>{val.templateFields}</p>

                            }, this)
```

Is it really that difficult in react to get a simple promise and use it?Is there a better way to do it that I might not know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, always use arrow functions instead of classic `function` declaration so you have `this` context passed along automatically.

Regarding your `console.log` do not try to log the state after you set it in `componentDidMount` the setState, and you request, are asynchronous.

You should always log the state in the render, or sometimes maybe in the `componentDidUpdate` eventually.

Take a look at this, this should work:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://nextgen-bcs-dev-1008264651.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/templateConfig/site6/VAULT`)
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                data: response.data
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

render () {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    return (
        <ul className="filter-options">
            {
                this.state.data.map((val) => {
                    <p>{val.templateFields}</p>
                })
            }
        </ul>
    );
}
```

If it doesn't, then your issue is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In `react` use arrow functions because `react` is one way binding and other issue is if you want to render some thing to `dom` then u need to return it. In your `map` function u only `iterate` but nothing return to `dom`

This is a simple code sample

```
export default class Test extends Component {
 state = {
   data: []
 };
 componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/').then(response => {
    this.setState({
      data: response.data
    });
  });
}
render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <ul className="filter-options">
       {
         this.state.data.map(function(val) {
           return(
             <p>{val.title}</p>
           )
         })}
     </ul>
   </div>
   );
 } 
}
```